# Problems after adding NSFetchedResultsController to a project

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I set up CoreData without `NSFetchedResultsController` and had everything saving fine. After switching to `NSFetchedResultsController`, I am getting a strange error when trying to save the image.

Here is the code I am using to save the image:

```
- (void)saveImage {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    TimeTravelFeed *timeTravelFeed = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TimeTravelFeed" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.thumbImage, 0.8f);

    [timeTravelFeed setValue:imageData forKey:@"imageData"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    //[tableView reloadData];        
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
-[_PFExternalReferenceData compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1669fb40
2013-12-08 10:09:49.442 Time Travel[830:60b] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  
-[_PFExternalReferenceData compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1669fb40 with userInfo (null)
2013-12-08 10:09:49.443 Time Travel[830:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_PFExternalReferenceData compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1669fb40'
```

Here is the code for NSFetchedResultsController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];

}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"TimeTravelFeed" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"imageData" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Comment: I cannot see an error in this part of your code. Perhaps set a breakpoint on "All Objective-C exceptions" to locate the problem.

Comment: Where should I be calling it? After adding the code for NSFEtchedResultsController, I didn't know what I needed to add to the old block of code I used to save the Image? What do I need to add? @nhgrif

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController is used to display Core Data objects in a table view, and is completely independent of how you *add* objects. As I said, your code seems to be OK, and the problem is somewhere else. - You have to locate the problem somehow (e.g. with an exception breakpoint).

Comment: Here I added all of the code I added above. After I added the break point, it stops on the line of code meant to handle errors @MartinR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"imageData" ascending:NO];
```

You cannot sort on a "Binary Data" attribute. A fetched results controller
needs a sort descriptor, so you should use a different attribute, e.g. a string, number or date. For example

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
```

where "creationDate" is an attribute (type "Date") and set when the object is created:

```
[timeTravelFeed setValue:imageData forKey:@"imageData"];
[timeTravelFeed setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"creationDate"];
```

Comment: Can you just sort newest to oldest. I only have one attribute in the entity I am trying to display in the table

Comment: I agree with Martin. Put an additional attribute like a date and use it to sort objects. @user3072540

Comment: @user3072540: Then you have to add a "creationDate" attribute (type "Date") and use that in the sort descriptor. When creating objects, set `[timeTravelFeed setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"creationDate"];`

Answer (score 1):

Go to your DBfile, select entity named "TimeTravelFeed" and select key "imageData". Set properties. 
[image]

Comment: NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"imageData" ascending:NO]; I think sort descriptor can't compare by this.

Comment: Try ty add any other attribute. Maybe file size or timestamp for sort.