# After saving to CoreData once, I receive error "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: swift, core-data

The problem is that I cannot save to Core Data again after the first time. According to similar questions it may have something to do with the SortDescriptor inside FetchRequest (ContentView) but I cannot figure out what change to make. Help would be very appreciated. Thank you

Edit: That other question does not unfortunately work, it is from 7 years ago, before swift even existed, which I cannot apply to/does not help.

Edit: I have removed the sorting the Binary Data, but the Error still persists

Core Data xcdatamodeld File:

img : Binary Data
date: String

I receive the error:

> -[_PFExternalReferenceData compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003c35810 with userInfo (null)

Here is the CameraView Component, where the ViewContext.save() happens, triggering the error:

```
struct CameraView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@State private var showSheet: Bool = false
@State private var showImagePicker: Bool = false
@State private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera

@State private var image: UIImage?

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        
        VStack{
            Button(action: saveImage, label: {
                Text("Save Image")
            }).foregroundColor(.black)
            Image(uiImage: image ?? UIImage(named: "placeholder")!)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width:300, height: 300)
            
            Button("Choose Picture") {
                self.showSheet = true
                
            }.foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding()
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Select Photo"),
                    message: Text("Choose"),
                    buttons:[
                        .default(Text("Photo Library")) {
                            self.showImagePicker = true
                            self.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                        },
                        .default(Text("Camera")) {
                            self.showImagePicker = true
                            self.sourceType = .camera
                        },
                        .cancel()
                    ]
                )
            }
            
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage){
            ImagePicker(image: self.$image, isShown: self.$showImagePicker, sourceType: self.sourceType)
        }
        
    }
    .navigationTitle("Take a Picture")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .padding(0)
    
}


func saveImage () {
    print("saving to jpegData")
    
    let pickedImage = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
    let drawing  = Drawing(context: viewContext)
    
    
    let date = Date()
    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let formattedDate = format.string(from: date)
    
    drawing.img = pickedImage
    drawing.date = "Sun 2 May"
    print(pickedImage!)
    
    do {
    try viewContext.save()
    print("Image is saved")
    } catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
    
    
}
```

}

Here is my App View, where I pass the managedObjectContext Environment into ContentView:

```
struct Draw_DailyApp: App {

let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
@Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase



@State var showOrderSheet = false


// Creating a global environment and placing it into the environment
@ObservedObject var searchObjectController: SearchObjectController = SearchObjectController()


var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
            .environmentObject(self.searchObjectController)
    }
    .onChange(of: scenePhase) { _ in
        persistenceController.save()
    }
}
```

}

The Content View, where the FetchRequest is called. It is compose of Tab Views, and then the Camera is a Navigation link inside Home View (But I dont reckon that is the issue here)

```
struct ContentView: View {

init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

  }

@FetchRequest(entity: Drawing.entity(),
              sortDescriptors: [
                NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Drawing.img, ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Drawing.date, ascending: true)
              ]
)
var orders: FetchedResults<Drawing>

var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(orders, id: \.self, content: { drawing in
                Text(drawing.date ?? "Unknown")
            })
        }

    
    
    TabView {
        MoodboardView()
            .tabItem{
                Label("mood", systemImage: "lightbulb")
            }
        HomeView()
            .tabItem{
                Label("home", systemImage: "list.dash")
            }
        SketchbookView()
            .tabItem{
                Label("sketchbook", systemImage: "pencil")
            }
        TipsView()
            .tabItem{
                Label("tips", systemImage: "book")
            }


    }.accentColor(.white)
}
```

}

Similar questions which I tried before posting this question seemed to ask for the call stack so please let me know if I should provide it here

Comment: I have no idea about the crash but why are you sorting on binary data (Drawing.img)? Less related but why store a date as a string and why use a hardcoded value for it?

Comment: Actually, I found this duplicate question and it looks like the sorting is the issue here. Does this answer your question? [Problems after adding NSFetchedResultsController to a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457013/problems-after-adding-nsfetchedresultscontroller-to-a-project)

Comment: Thanks for answering Joakim. Im very new to Core Data, so I sorted the binary data because I assume that was the same way process as the string from this tutorial: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-core-data-fetch-request-using-fetchrequest

Comment: (Oh the date is just a way for me to test, if strings work). I then saved the Image into Core from this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-core-data-objects-from-swiftui-views.

Comment: That duplicate tutorial you found looks like a possible fix, but im not sure how to apply it to mine. Are you suggesting to remove the Binary Data SortDescriptor? I just tried that now, but received the same error

Comment: Yes you should definitely remove that sort descriptor and only sort on types like String, Date, Int etc

Comment: Ive removed that thanks, but that didnt solve the issue. And the duplication question uses code from 7 years ago so the functions have changed alot and I cant work out how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

@Joakin Danielson I sincerely apologize. I removed the wrong line. The Core Data FetchRequest Is working fine now becasue I removed the line sorting on Binary Data. Thanks very much, well appreciated!